# f# linked list implementing with records

Tags: f#, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list in f# using records. I know I can use the build in list type but this is for learning purposes. My type is:

```
type Cell = { data : int; next : RList}
and RList = Cell option ref
```

And I'd like to make a simple insert function, but I'm told that f# is expecting a boolean but was given an expression of type unit. I'm wondering if this means I've formatted my if/else statement incorrectly

```
let rec insert comp (item: int) (list: RList) =
    let c = {data = item; next = ref None}
    match !list with
     | None -> list = cellToRList c
     | Some {data = d; next = remaining} -> 
        if (comp(item, d)) then
            c.next := !remaining
            remaining := ref c (* compiler indicates error here *)
        else insert comp item remaining
```

Note: comp is any comparison function taking (item, d) as input and outputting true or false ex:

```
let compare (x, y) = x > y
```

My goal is simply to insert a new cell with data = item if compare outputs true. In the example above it could be used to insert into a sorted list and maintain sorted-ness. The entire function should return type unit. Any hint as to why my interpreter is looking for a boolean would be appreciated!

Note: I'm very new to F#

====

Fixed with improvements Courtesy of Foggy, Mikhail, and Fyodor

```
type Cell = { data : int; next : (Cell option) ref}

let rec insert compare (item: int) (list: (Cell option) ref) : unit =
    let c = {data = item; next = ref None}
    match !list with
    | None -> list := Some c
    | Some {data = d; next = remaining} -> 
        if (compare(d, item)) then
            c.next := !remaining
            remaining := Some c
        else insert compare item remaining
```

Comment: That doesn't answer your question, but you don't need RList : `type Cell = { data : int; next : Cell option}` https://dotnetfiddle.net/VzZwnb

Comment: It's more of a convenience wrapper, unless you think it's less convenient?

Comment: Of course, `RList` redundant.

Comment: Only yesterday there was a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35816215/180286

Comment: Also, note that mutable data structures are bleh. The only advantage they have over immutable ones is that they _may, in principle_, be made more performant. But this does not apply to singly linked list.

Comment: I think the use of 'mutable' in the beginning of learning F# will only harm.

Comment: Incidentally I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889171/f-custom-linked-list-and-references

Comment: Thanks! Although I did it slightly differently I have no problem implementing an append function. I think I'm doing something wrong with my pattern matching... I just have no idea what...

Comment: @Sunny have you looked at the link I posted?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of it Fyodor, but I'm afraid I barely understand it... I thought the <- and := operators were the same... Edit: OH looking at the wrong line of code...

Comment: Of course it's a type error, when is it ever not with F#. Thank you all for the help!!!

Comment: Can you try to write code without the 'ref Cell'? It will be much more useful.

Comment: Sure, I had almost forgotten to post fixed code

Comment: @Foggy you are right, it is nicer without the RList, at least for this function

Comment: For learning purpose it is probably better to use a Discriminated Union for a list. Something like. `type MyList<'a> = | End | Cons of 'a * MyList<'a>`

Comment: As an exercise I wrote a function 'insert' without using the 'ref'. If you want, we can compare the result :)

Comment: I tried to move my answer from the question to a new answer but I guess it didn't work. Not gonna question it. I've added it to the question now. @FoggyFinder

Comment: I got this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qQYQ5f

Comment: but I think can write a little bit easier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return a bool from your `None` match:

```
| None -> list = cellToRList c
```

Equals sign is a comparison operator here. So the compiler infers the function to return `bool`, while I guess your intention is to return `unit`.

In any case, whenever you don't understand the inferred types of your functions, try annotating them explicitly. In your case, make it

```
let rec insert comp (item: int) (list: RList) : unit =
```

And you will see the problem that I described above.

You may want to remove type annotation once everything compiles.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now! Also FYI when I annotate it explicitly the compiler will find the error on the correct line.